# After installing unity apk into android icon displaying twisely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, manifest

After installing Unity apk into my device icon displaying two times

i have make sure that launcher should only one in all the manifest file

[Here is snap of Manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOSos.png)

Comment: Post the code instead of snapshot

Comment: Try changing Texture Import settings "WrapMode" to "Clamp".

Comment: Finally,I decompile the my apk  and check manifest file so i got an idea that there is something(~Which contain launcher launcher intent) that **launcher** tag inside that **plugin xml node**. Actually i was't aware of that plugin which is used by other developer. so when we build apk it automatically get all manifest elements inside unity apk manifest it result to **generate two times main activity launch intent**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, The issue has been resolved for icon T wisely visibility  (~Problem solution :  Before i have Added custom plug-in,which is  containing the launcher activity so removed that line. THIS LINE IS REMOVED FROM MANIFEST OF CUSTOM PLUGIN --> category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")